# Java - How do I set a random seed to a static Random member?

Tags: java, random, random-seed

This is probably a duplicate, but I didn't find an answer specifically with Random and seeding it.

I'm currently refactoring a project where I use Random instances quite frequently across several other classes (until now I had all of these code snippets inside a Main class, so I could get by with just using one instance). For testing and reproducability purposes I want to set a seed to my Random member, something like this:

```
Random rand = new Random();  
int seed = rand.nextInt();
rand.setSeed(seed);
System.out.println(seed);
```

(Printed as a console output for now, should probably save it to a file).
I also made a method that uses `rand.nextInt()`, but a bit less cumbersome and that bypasses `nextInt()`'s positive bound parameter restriction:

```
public static int enhancedRandInt(int max, int min){
    if(min>max)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Min cannot exceed max.");
    else return min==max?min:rand.nextInt(max-min)+min;
}
```

I plan to use this method several times across several classes so I figured I'd make it static. That of course requires `rand` to be static as well, but then I run into a problem of converting my seeding procedure to be all static. I guess I could make a new temporary Random instance to get the seed from and then set that to the now static `rand` in my `main()`. Is that solution good practice? Should I forgo making `enhancedRandInt` static to begin with?

Comment: Consider wrapping the `Random` in a helper class, such as `RandomWrapper`.  There could be multiple instances of that class, with each instance accepting a seed value through its constructor.  For testing, mock the class and have it return whatever value is needed to test the class under test.  And no need to make anything static.

Comment: You can create it and seed it (and print the seed) in a [static initialization block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html).